# AWS Websocket API Gateway pigwManagementApi.postToConnection time out Lambda + VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-vpc

I have implemented WebSockets using AWS lambda and API gateway, it seemed to work fine until I moved it behind a VPC, right now I am able to connect to the WSS and it is able to communicate with dynamodb (through VPC endpoint) but when I try to send data to a connected connection: apigwManagementApi.postToConnection(xxx)
I get timeout (lambda function times out)

Comment: Have you given corresponding permission to Lambda functions i.e. action "execute-api:ManageConnections" on the api resource.

Answer (score 0):

1. Did you grant "execute-api:ManageConnections" permission?
   You must have the appropriate IAM permissions to send messages from Lambda to clients using API Gateway.
   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-websocket-control-access-iam.html
2. Is the EndPoint accurate?
   `https://i5uml****.execute-api.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com/dev` should look like this.
   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/ApiGatewayManagementApi.html
3. Is your VPC configuration set up?
   Lambda must not have a VPC configuration.
   When a VPC is enabled, all routing rules in the VPC and subnets are applied.
   https://stackoverflow.com/a/58559527/10890622

If the VPC configuration is absolutely necessary, you must create and add a Private VPC.